# what is dispatchEvent in Flash AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

Hi all i want to know what is **dispatchEvent** in **AS3**.
I didn't get any idea while Googling it. :( 
So please help me

**Edit 1:**

```
public static  const SET_VOLUME:String = "setVolume";

private function onclick(evt:MouseEvent):void {
            soundClip.scaleX = 0;
            dispatchEvent(new Event(SET_VOLUME));

        }
```

what does this means?? (

Comment: @coderex, Please mark your questions as answered when they are answered!

Answer (score 15):

An example might help? If you have Flash IDE, try this in your timeline:

```
var ball:Shape = new Shape();
ball.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
ball.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 30);
ball.graphics.endFill();
addChild(ball);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveListener);
addEventListener("myCustomEvent", myCustomEventListener);

function mouseMoveListener(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    dispatchEvent(new Event("myCustomEvent"));
}

function myCustomEventListener(event:Event):void
{
    ball.x = stage.mouseX;
    ball.y = stage.mouseY;
}
```

This is code demonstrates how the *addEventListener* and *dispatchEvent* are counterparts. The *MOUSE_MOVE* event is dispatched internally, but you can dispatch your own events just like the *MOUSE_MOVE* using *dispatchEvent*.

What happens in this code is that a *MOUSE_MOVE* from the stage is detected, but rather than handle that in the *mouseMoveListener*, you dispatch another event (called *myCustomEvemt*) which is handled in the *myCustomEventListener* instead. It works just like the *MOUSE_MOVE* event, only you dispatched the event instead of the flash player.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do not forget to add those imports at the begin of the file...
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.events.*

Thank You alecmce
Best regards

Answer (score 6):

Say there are two classes : A and B . Now you want that "functionAfterMyFun" should occur after myFun has occured in class B. Then you would use dispatchEvent in class B's function myfun().

```
class A 
{

function A()
{
  objectOfB.addEventListener( "myFun_Happened",  functionAfterMyFun)
}

function functionAfterMyFun()
{
    //do something after myFun has happened in class B 
}

}

class B
{
function myfun()
{
dispatchEvent(new Event("myFun_Happened"));
}


}
```

Comment: 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type flash.events:Event. :( Am I missing an import?

Comment: ah sorry, there was a typo. I just edited it again.
 
dispatchEvent ( new Event ("myFun_Happened"));

Comment: Good explanation! Short and to the point.
So basically anyone who is interested and has access to the Event Dispatcher object can listen to that object.

Answer (score 3):

Basically it's a mechanism to notify objects that something has happened.  When you dispatch an event, something needs to be listening for that event.

It's basically like making a telephone call ( dispatchEvent(new CallEvent(CallEvent.CALL)) ).  If the person you are trying to ring isn't in, they aren't listening to the telephone event, so they can't do anything about it.  If they are in ( addEventListener(CallEvent.Call, answerHandler) ), they can answer it, maybe send it straight to voice mail.

For a full rundown, try reading this article from adobe.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3_02.html

A lot of programming languages make use of events so it's very worth while getting to grips with it.

James

**Response to Edit1**

It looks to me like you have a method that has been set up to handle a MouseEvent.Click on some object somewhere.  When that happens it sets another objects scaleX property to 0 (making it invisible).  A new Event is then Dispatched with the type set to "setVolume".  This on it's own wouldn't do anything.  Somewhere else this is probably a line looks a little like addEventListener("setVolume", doSomethingMethod); .  When the original method is fired (seemingly a mouse click), the doSomethingMethod should fire.

Comment: ok i have one doubt please check my questions edit 1: section

Comment: When onclick() is called the "setVolume" will be raised, notifying any subscribers (that subscribed to "setVolume" by calling addEventListener).

Answer (score -2):

`addaddEventListener()` is like to make your prenuptial agreement.
For instance, if your wife have another man outsides, you will get $100 from your wife.F ortunately, that happens.
`dispatchEvent()` means that you will get $100.